# Selecting a pixel according to its coordinates in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

For a specific pixel, I can get its location by `ee.Image.pixelLonLat()` or `ee.Image.pixelCoordinates(projection)` functions. However, can I select a pixel using its pixel coordinates? In the following code, I extract the location values of a pixel corresponding to a point. Then I want to use these values as conditions to select the pixel in the image and replace its flag value .

```
var point = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([118.99246144997284, 37.976371825637756]);

var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_121034_20200314');

image = image.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
             .addBands(ee.Image(0).rename("Flag"));
print(image);
Map.addLayer(image, {},'image');
Map.centerObject(image, 8);

Map.addLayer(point);

//Get the pixel in which the point is located
var pointPixel = image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), geometry: point});
print(pointPixel,'pointPixel');
  
//Get the location of pointPixel
var SP_latitude = ee.Number(pointPixel.get('latitude'));
var SP_longitude = ee.Number(pointPixel.get('longitude'));
print(SP_latitude);
print(SP_longitude);

//Set the flag of the pointPixel as 1
image = image.select('Flag').where(image.select('longitude').eq(SP_longitude)
                                       .and(image.select('latitude').eq(SP_latitude)),1);
print(image);
Map.addLayer(image, {bands:'Flag'},'flag');
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do an exact comparison isn't a good plan due to rounding.

You can just create an image with the point(s) you want to replace using `image.paint()`, and use that with `image.where()`to do replacement at those locations.

```
var replacement = ee.Image(0).paint(point, 1)
image = image.select('Flag').where(replacement, 1);
```

But the last assignment replaces the whole image, which is probably not what you intended.  More likely you just want to add the flag band back into the image, with overwrite: true.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a59068602b7c14683c90aa813b844118

Comment: Thank you very much for your instruction. The last assignment is to indicate that the pixel is used if its flag value is 1. However, image.paint() can only indicate the point location, while in the other places within this pixel, the flag value is still 0. How can I assign the flag value to the whole pixel, rather than a specific location within the pixel?

Comment: When you paint a point into an image, it occupies a whole pixel.

Comment: I have examined the point carefully, but it doesn't occupy a whole pixel. In the following code, I buffer the point to a circle with 10 m and paint it to the image. Using the inspector, it is seen that the flag value is 1 within the circle, meanwhile is 0 in the rest part of the pixel.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/772f3b9298a6ce58cf3082d2ee812c73